# Powershell's memory limits?

Tags: .net, powershell

why does this not reach `$StringBuilder.MaxCapacity` (either 2GB) in Windows's Powershell ?

```
$StringBuilder = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new()
$nu_s = 0
$nu = 100000000
while ( $null -ne $StringBuilder.Append([char[]]::new($nu)).ToString() ) {
    $nu_s = $nu_s + $nu
}
while ($nu -gt 1) {
    # $null = $StringBuilder.Remove($nu_s, $StringBuilder.Length - $nu_s)
    $nu = $nu / 10
    while ( $null -ne $StringBuilder.Append([char[]]::new($nu)).ToString() ) {
        $nu_s = $nu_s + $nu
    }
}
Write-Host $nu_s, $StringBuilder.MaxCapacity
$StringBuilder.Clear()
```

i suppose this is related to some memory limits in P, does anyone know which that is and how to fix ?

edit_1: ~~also, the StringBuilder's Constructor doesn't accept values higher than the script provide .~~ ( it does, but still less than `$StringBuilder.MaxCapacity` )

edit_2: i tried using `[GC]::Collect()`, `[GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()` and `$v.Finalize()`, no changes .

edit_3: im giving up, the s**t P refuses to allow to fix this . im going with all-cases string and array limits: 200 000 000 Bytes/items; and preferable: 100 000 000 Bytes/items . (i had this issue with array-related scripts too)

Comment: the limit is on .NET and has nothing to do with PowerShell. How much memory do you have? How much contiguous free memory do you have? What are the expected and real outputs of the program?

Comment: @phuclv i have 14+GB free for it to run . _ _ expected output is described by the 2nd paragraph . (same as current)

Comment: @phuclv `System.Text.StringBuilder` doesn't accept any type of preallocated memory, so idk how its intended to work if it doesn't use it fully auto .

Comment: What is the ultimate problem you're trying to solve? If this is just for fun/education it's a different story from trying to overcome actual memory limitations in a real problem (which may not necessarily involve pushing `StringBuilder` to its limits).

Comment: @JeroenMostert its an { error-handling [^] performance } issue .

Comment: We have edit history on SO. There's no need to litter questions and/or answers with little "edit" notes.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever maybe the system misses a "minor" tag for edits, or something . when i think of other stuff, i can use the time more effectively by improving different posts . by the way, the delay for accepting own answer as solution is nonsense, because of it i wouldn't do so at all, if my attention wasn't brought here by comment to the answer .

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever ability to manually merge older edits would help too .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit_final

- `<<StringBuilder>>.Append` crashes before reaching `<<StringBuilder>>.MaxCapacity` , because it's content is not stored with the most efficient layout, use 5823-items `[char[]]` -s to store the maximum of items .

  also, notice that maximum of items is specified by that `<<StringBuilder>>.Length` is limited to the `[int]` 's max . [pointed out by @phuclv]
- the issue when i can't use more than 2GB of memory, is inherited from the environment . it can be determined by:

  - in case its because the Powershell runs in 32-bit -- `[Environment]::Is64BitProcess` . [pointed out by @phuclv]
  - as a workaround, loading the memory until limit is reached, using
    analog of the script below .
- also, `[char]` is a 2-bytes UTF-16 item, `[System.Array]` is limited to about 2GB (a bit more) .

edit: also see the comments below .

i've **read** that Windows ~processes by default get a limit of 2GB of Primary Storage . (it would limit the StringBuilder's content)

this script should get the exact value which can be used as a limit .

- i get different max values in different environments . but these are: about 2GB and about 4GB, and as i've **read**, the OS's limit can be increased to 3GB and 4GB, so i assume that this limit is the reason of the issue .
- PrivateMemorySize64 results differ about 2KB (and each the other, except SystemMemory, differ too), so the limit still needs a margin, that makes it not false-proof, but unless someone posts how to get Powershell's view of it's resources, this is the workaround provided .

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
$StringBuilder = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new()
$Process = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess()
$showMemoryLoad = {
    Write-Host ''
    $args[0].Refresh()
    Write-Host "PagedMemorySize64               = $($args[0].PagedMemorySize64)"        # prob equal to PrivateMemorySize64
    Write-Host "PrivateMemorySize64             = $($args[0].PrivateMemorySize64)"
    Write-Host "PagedSystemMemorySize64         = $($args[0].PagedSystemMemorySize64)"
    Write-Host "physical memory currently used  = $($args[0].WorkingSet64)"
    Write-Host "NonpagedSystemMemorySize64      = $($args[0].NonpagedSystemMemorySize64)"
    Write-Host "VirtualMemorySize64             = $($args[0].VirtualMemorySize64)"
}

$limit = 10000000000
$nu_sc = $limit / 10 * 10
while ($nu_sc -gt 1) { $nu_sc = $nu_sc / 10
    :sc for ($nu_re_sc = 0; $nu_re_sc -lt 9; $nu_re_sc++) {
        $limit = $limit - $nu_sc
        Write-Host ''
        Write-Host $limit
    
        $null = $StringBuilder.Clear()
        $nu = 100000000 * 10
        while ($nu -gt 1) {
            $nu = $nu / 10
            Write-Host ''
            Write-Host "$nu $($Process.PrivateMemorySize64) $($StringBuilder.Length)"
            while (($limit - $Process.PrivateMemorySize64) -gt ($nu * 1)) {
                $v = $StringBuilder.Append([char[]]::new($nu))
                if ($null -eq $v) {continue sc}
                $v = $null
            }
        }
        
        $limit = $limit + $nu_sc
        break
    }
}
& $showMemoryLoad $Process
Write-Host ''
Write-Host $StringBuilder.Length, $StringBuilder.MaxCapacity $limit
```

Comment: `Windows ~processes by default get a limit of 2GB of Primary Storage` this is absolutely nonsense. There's no such thing as "Primary Storage" in a process. 32-bit processes get 2GB of address space by default, or 3GB on 32-bit Windows and 4GB on 64-bit Windows when `/largeaddressaware` flag is enabled. 64-bit processes currently get 128TB of address space. PowerShell on 64-bit Windows has 64-bit version in system32 and 32-bit version in sysWOW64, but one almost never runs the 32-bit version so the address space would almost always be larger. The limit is due to the use of int in .NET objects

Comment: @phuclv so the limit is from .NET using int to map it's items stored in Primary Storage, though OS provides it 128TB, and the case when i get a ~2GB limit is because that (not standard) environment runs in 32bit ?? _ _ if so, from perspective of .NET user it makes no difference, but thanks for clarification . _ _ maybe you know why i get some-KB difference in PrivateMemorySize64 results in the same environment ?

Comment: thanks to help of discord, appears that the PrivateMemorySize64 difference is nothing other that the expected runtime system's stuff .

Comment: as said, there's no such thing as "Primary Storage". In .NET the maximum size for an object is 2GB because the `Length` property in .NET is an `int`. Only later `LongLength` is added to some objects and they can grow larger than 2GB if `gcAllowVeryLargeObjects` is enabled. First you need to make sure that powershell is 64-bit

Comment: @phuclv there is always such thing, otherwise the PC/runtime just won't work . you are partially right, appears that Length is the reason, but this is wrong: `maximum size for an object is 2GB` ; in StringBuilder the length limits total of chars . thanks for your contribution .

Comment: @phuclv . "RAM" is a type of storage used for Primary Storage . trough all the subject, PM (and it's emulation by Windows using a part of Secondary Storage) is the storage used . _ _ in case of StringBuilder the limit has nothing to do with space (GB) . _ _ search PM on Wikipedia . _ _ "memory" means any storage for data (or even wider), its used for PM fairly incorrectly .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248034/discussion-between-irvnriir-and-phuclv).